# I need to display full screen video using ExoPlayer in PIP mode on Android

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-picture-in-picture

I have just implemented PIP (Picture in picture) mode in Android for my project. It works fine except that in pip mode, video shows a white stripe at the bottom. I have hidden all other UI elements but it still shows.
I was wondering if other people had such an issue and how they solved it?

I am using Exoplayer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it was happening after debugging the layout. it was being caused by extra margin. it had nothing to do with Exoplayer as such.
Thank you.